# setScaleType and alignment

Tags: android, alignment, imageview, image-resizing

I want to scale image using setScaleType and align left + center vertically
I see only options ScaleType.FIT_START (left, top) ScaleType.FIT_CENTER and ScaleType.FIT_END (right, bottom)
How I can combine them to get left aligned vertically centered image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do this with scale Matrix. Here is some [tutorial](http://www.anddev.org/resize_and_rotate_image_-_example-t621.html).